# Is it possible to create facebook canvas application using heroku, after removing of Cloud Integration service

Tags: facebook, heroku, facebook-canvas

I'm a newbie in using Heroku and in developing for Facebook.
I've created an application for facebook using Heroku following [the guide *Developing Facebook Apps on Heroku*](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook)

It created a website which is hosted in Heroku and using Facebook features.

**My question is if it's possible to create something like that (using Heroku) as an App in Facebook (canvas application) ?**

I found this guide: [*Building a Facebook Application With Ruby*](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook-ruby)

Unfortunately it's written there:

> Facebook has removed the Facebook Cloud Integration service. No new applications can be created through this service. Existing applications will continue to operate.

any ideas ?